# how many values exists in a range of values? excel

Tags: excel, range, belongs-to

i'd like to find how many values exists in particular range of  values in excel
for example i have values

```
116, 118, 118, 118, 118, 119, 120, 120, 121, 121... etc
```

and let's say my range is:

```
from 110 to 119 and from 120 to 129
```

and i would like to find out how many of them belongs to first range and how many to the second

i made a terrible image but i hope it will help to understand the problem
[enter image Description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41TaT.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `COUNTIFS` function

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&B1, A:A,"<="&C1)
```

Where your values are in `A:A`, your lower bound in `B1` and upper bound in `C1`. Drag the formula down as necessary.